# Adding not multiplying

Tags: c++

I am teaching myself C++, starting on the basics have written this:

```
// stringstreams
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string mystr;
    int price = 0;
    int quantity = 0;
    int total = price * quantity;

    cout << "------------------------------------------------------" << '/n';
    cout << "-----------------Welcome to the shop!-----------------" << '/n';
    cout << "------------------------------------------------------" << '/n';
    cout << "Enter price of item" << '/n';
    getline(cin, mystr);
    stringstream(mystr) >> price;
    cout << "How Many do you want?" << '/n';
    getline(cin, mystr);
    stringstream(mystr) >> quantity;
    cout << "you want this many: " << quantity << '/n';
    cout << "at this price: " << price << '/n';
    cout << "this would cost you: " << total << " pounds" << '/n';

    if (total >= 20)
    {
        cout << "here is a discount of " << total / 20 << '/n';
    }
    else if (total >= 10)
    {
        cout << "here is a discount of " << total / 10 << '/n';
    }
    else
    {

        cout << "sorry no discount" << '/n';
    };
}
```

My only problem is - its adding the total price instead of multiplying. I feel I am missing something very obvious but after an hour I cant seem to find out what it is, I have tried declaring total further down the code which has not worked, I have also tried putting the total in brackets still nothing.

What am I missing?

-- as an example --
10 units at the cost of 10 each, should come out at 100, not 20 as it does on my code

[image: not adding]

Comment: `cout << "this would cost you: " << total << " pounds" << '/n';` Do you know what `total` is here ?

Comment: I wonder if the OP has come from a prolog background?

Comment: Rolled-back the question to show the _whole_ originally-stated problem, as covered in existing answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not doing *anything* with the total price, since it'll always be `0`.

```
int total = price * quantity;
```

The result of the multiplication is performed and "saved" at *this* point, and doesn't change later even if `price` and `quantity` do.

You should put this line *after* the lines where you truly set the values of `price` and `quantity`.

As for your question about "adding not multiplying", with the fix in place as above **[the value output is correct](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08deae7469e49f24)**, so you must be doing something wrong that we can't see. Check that you're running *this* code, and not some other piece of code.

Also, you've consistently written `/n`, whereas it should be `\n` (which further suggests that your screenshot is not from running *this* code). In fact, the two before your prompt for input should be `endl`, to ensure that the prompt is flushed to the console.

Comment: `'\n'` should be `endl`

Comment: @Skizz certainly not all of them.

Comment: @Skizz: Why's that, then? I can see two that should be, and no others.

Comment: Going to accept this as answer, not sure what the fix was but you helped most I think.

Comment: @Marriott81: The fix was _all the things listed above_, followed by recompiling your code, as I suggested.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: All of them! In my build using DevStudio2008, the `'/n'` is displayed as `12142` as the literal is upcasted to an integer.

Comment: @Skizz: Yes, `'/n'` is wrong, as I've already said a couple of times. That does not mean that _all_ the `'\n'` (note the corrected backslash) should be `std::endl`.

Answer (score 2):

you are calculating the total at the wrong place.
Initially, you calculate `total = price * quantity`, with `price = 0` and `quantity = 0`, and this will assign `0` to `total`. Then after inputting the `quantity` and `price`, you do not recalculate the `total`, so it gives you the wrong result.

My suggestion is to put
`total = price * quantity;` after `stringstream(mystr) >> quantity;`

Comment: have moved it down so its just above the cout << you want this many but they are still adding?

Comment: @Marriott81: Not possible. Give examples!

Comment: @Marriott81: You need to give examples of input and corresponding output. `*` does _not_ perform addition.

Comment: as in if you put in 10 units, at 10 each it should come out at 100 not 20?

Comment: @Marriott81: [It _does_ output 100](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08deae7469e49f24).

Comment: there is my problem, it Should, but it does not on my screen?

Comment: @Marriott81: Then you are doing something different on your screen than you are telling us, and we cannot help directly. Did you forget to recompile your program after making some code changes?

Comment: @Marriott81: Check my previous comment ;p

Comment: recompiled, now it just rapidly exits does not hold after you are done =\ - nvm thats working, just still not multiplying

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48365/discussion-between-marriott81-and-lightness-races-in-orbit)

Comment: I really find it hard to believe that you're running the code you've shown us, when your line endings are `/n` not `\n` (which is wrong and won't work) yet your screenshot shows the result of good line endings.

Comment: a: I did not know they were wrong b:I have better things to do than sit here trolling stack, literally that code (which is posted above) is in my compiler, I run it, it works fine other than it does not multiply.

Comment: @Marriott81: I'm not accusing you of "trolling"; I am telling you with my experience and expertise what I think is wrong with your problem. If you do not wish to listen to me and consider what I'm saying, then that's your choice. It is now up to you to go and investigate that. Good luck.

Comment: thanks, have gone through and changed them all to \ now

Comment: Also, it's called "Stack Overflow", not "stack".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit now whos trolling :P, not sure what it was, but I went through and rewrote it all and it worked, I dunno if it was wrong code (tho I had no other forms open?)

Comment: @Marriott81: If you ever encounter lightness, racing around in an orbit of some description, trust it.

Answer (score 1):

```
auto total = [&]() { return price * quantity; };
```

and then use `total()`

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/27ba0fa6978ec9e1

Comment: For someone who's stated they're learning C++, is a lambda based answer really suitable? Interesting, certainly.

Comment: @Skizz it's hard to answer for sure... but maybe, I would like also to suggest `auto` in replace of `int` ... Do you think learning C++ is really suitable for someone who just started learning programming?

Comment: What about `auto` instead of `int`? This way it looks like `total` being a number...

Comment: this is not my first language, I am just expanding into c++ in prerperation for objective C

Comment: @Heather: That is whole topic right there really. I guess if you've never programmed anything then C++ might not be ideal (I started on ZX80 Basic!). If there's some previous experience, then why not. But, you need to grasp the fundamentals before getting onto the more complex stuff (like a med student doing brain surgery)

Comment: @Marriott81 Start directly with objC. C++ is a bit detour for you. It won't help you.

Comment: This is an interesting snippet of code, especially when thinking about how an optimiser would tackle it. Is the compiler smart enough to reuse the result of the first `total()` call in subsequent calls to `total()`, provided the `price` and `quantity` remain unchanged. Yeah, I know in this case it makes little difference and premature optimisation blah blah blah, but if the lambda was more complex or used a lot, what are the potential costs of using lambdas? Hmmm...research time! (Anything to avoid writing user guides)

Comment: @Heather: hey, we could go all enterprisey and make `total` a web service and let the server do all the tricky messing about with maths! A bit of REST and XML, chuck in a bit of JSON and any other buzzword to get a full house! :-)